# How to create this widget like this image in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, image, stack

I want to create applicants page to show who applied my demand, but before do it I want to show it like this image.

[image]

Comment: Please share more details. What have you tried? What issue you are facing?

Comment: I don't have any issue , I just wanted to know how to create like this widget

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Answer (score 1):

There could be more than one way to do it. One of which is using `Row` and `Stack`. Try the below snippet, it will help you get started:

```
Row(
                children: [
                  const Expanded(child: Text("Applications")),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 130,
                    child: Stack(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      clipBehavior: Clip.none,
                      fit: StackFit.loose,
                      children: [
                        Positioned(
                            right: 15,
                            child: Container(
                              height: 40,
                              width: 40,
                              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                  color: Colors.black
                              ),
                              child: Image.asset("assets/img.png"),
                            )
                        ),
                        Container(
                          height: 40,
                          width: 40,
                          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                              shape: BoxShape.circle,
                              color: Colors.black
                          ),
                          child: Image.asset("assets/img.png"),
                        ),
                        Positioned(
                          left: 15,
                            child: Container(
                              height: 40,
                              width: 40,
                              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                  color: Colors.black
                              ),
                              child: Image.asset("assets/img.png"),
                            )
                        ),

                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  const Text("30"),
                  const Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios)
                ]
            ),
```